# Mplfinance and adding fill_between on subplot

Tags: mplfinance

I want to use 'fill_between' attribute on a subplot but I am unsuccessful.

Attribute works when **not** using on a subplot as per below example and screenshot:

```
list_dates = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
list_values = [10,11,12,13,14,15]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list_dates,list_values, list_values, list_values, list_values)), columns=['Dates', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
df.index = pd.date_range('1/1/2021',periods=(len(df)))

mpf.plot(df, type='line', ylim=(0,20), fill_between=df['Close'].values)
```

[image]

But when I try to get the same result using subplot the attribute does not seem to apply. What am I missing? Thanks in advance

```
list_dates = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
list_values = [10,11,12,13,14,15]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list_dates,list_values, list_values, list_values, list_values)), columns=['Dates', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
df.index = pd.date_range('1/1/2021',periods=(len(df)))

fig = mpf.figure(figsize=(12,9))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
mpf.plot(df,type='line', ylim=(0,20), ax=ax1,fill_between=df['Close'].values)
mpf.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`fill_between`** ***does*** work for "subplots," ***but only*** when those subplots are created using [**`mplfinance.make_addplot()`**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb).

You, however, are creating your subplot using [**external axes mode**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects#2-create-your-own-figure-and-axes-objects-and-pass-these-into-mplfinance--you-can-see-examples-of-how-to-do-this-here).  Mplfinance does not support `fill_between` in external axes mode because, in external axes mode, *the user owns the Axes object,* (not mplfinance) and the user can easily call `fill_between()` directly on the Axes object*.

---

As noted in the [**external axes mode documentation**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects#2-create-your-own-figure-and-axes-objects-and-pass-these-into-mplfinance--you-can-see-examples-of-how-to-do-this-here), the external axes method of subplotting is strongly discouraged, because you lose the benefits of mplfinance doing much of the work for you.  One should only use external axes mode when there is no other way to accomplish what you are trying to do.  Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of mplfinance.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for taking the time to answer my question. I also appreciate your work with this library. I'm a big fan. I will check the links provided and follow your advice